# Openssl, Java: unable to decrypt for long messages

Tags: java, encryption, openssl, aes

I am encrypting text using java and trying to decrypt it using Openssl on Linux. I am using AES-128 with CBC.

I receive a "bad decrypt" error from Openssl when I use Openssl to decrypt a 64-character-encrypted-string produced by Java. But if the string is 16 characters, Openssl is able to decrypt it properly.

I am running this on Linux:

```
echo ${encryptedText} | ./openssl aes-128-cbc -d -a -K $( echo -n ${KEY} | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X"') -iv $(echo -n ${IV} | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X"')
```

Note: $encryptedText, $KEY, $IV are passed as string and not hex. This command turns it into hex:
$( echo -n ${KEY} | hexdump -v -e '/1 "%02X"')

and receiving this error:

```
358048944:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:460:
```

My encryption code from Java, is basically:

```
import javax.crypto.*;

Cipher cipher;
SecretKey key;
String IV;
IvParameterSpec params;

cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
String randomString = GENERATE_RANDOM_TYPEABLE_ASCII(16_LENGTH);

key = new SecretKeySpec(randomString.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
IV = GENERATE_RANDOM_TYPEABLE_ASCII(16_LENGTH);
params = new IvParameterSpec(IV.getBytes("UTF-8"));

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, params);
byte[] encryptedTextBytes = cipher.doFinal((decryptedString).getBytes("UTF-8")); // decryptedString is passed as a parameter

String encryptedText = new Base64().encodeAsString(encryptedTextBytes);
return encryptedText;
```

What I don't understand is why I the crypto works for 16 character strings but fails for 64 character strings.

Another important thing to note is that if I decrypt the text using online tools such as http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/ the string decrypts perfectly. So I think my encryption is working fine but for some reason OpenSSL is giving problems.

Comment: It certainly can't work until you base64-decode the ciphertext before decrypting it with openssl.

Comment: @James Thats why I have -a flag in the openssl command above. Am I missing something? Thanks for the response

Comment: Oh yeah, I'd forgotten about that flag.

Comment: I don't see how it would differ for 16 vs. 64 bytes, but PKCS5 padding isn't well defined for AES.  Maybe try PKCS7 just in case Java is doing something weird with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not reproduced your problem but suspect this is causing you problems: the `Base64.encodeAsString()` function as you use it returns a long string as opposed to a block of 16 characters wide:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class B64Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] plaintext = new byte[100];
        String b64text = new Base64().encodeAsString(plaintext);
        System.out.println(b64text);
    }
}
```

gives the output

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==
```

If you want to feed that into `openssl` for decoding, you need to provide the additional option `-A` to make `openssl` base64 process the data on one line. Note that `-A` needs to be used together with `-a`, or with `-base64`, which is the same thing but more readable. This is explained in the documentation for [openssl enc](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/enc.html).

Alternatively, you can tell the `Base64()` constructor to insert line-breaks after, for example, 64 characters, like this:

```
String b64text = new Base64(64).encodeAsString(plaintext);
```

Comment: I changed to -A flag but I get the same issue. I also tried the 80 character line break (with -a flag) but I still get the same issue.

Comment: That is too bad. Would you be able to post actual example values for the required variables to simplify reproducing and analyzing the problem?

Comment: By the way, you said "changed" to `-A` flag. However, you should add it. Did you do that?

Comment: Playing around with `openssl`'s base64 functionality a bit more, it seems like the cut-off is at 64 bytes, not 80. Does that make any difference? (I updated the code example accordingly.)

Comment: I am away from my work laptop, I won't be able to give u any example values until Monday. 

By change I mean: I replaced -a to -A

Comment: OK, enjoy your weekend... You will need to use both `-a` and `-A` side-by-side. The documentation says for `-A`:  "if the `-a` option is set then base64 process[es] the data on one line.". Or use `-base64 -A` in stead of `-a -A`, which is the same but looks better.

Comment: For OpenSSL through 1.0.2 `-a/base64 -d` without `-A` the cutoff is 76 (NOT 80, or 64) base64 chars per line, which encodes 59 bytes. For OpenSSL 1.1.0 it is 1024 chars or 768 bytes. Even `-A` cuts off at a higher point, AFAICT 4000 bytes.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 : I tried `printf "MTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTAxMjM0NTY3ODkwMTIzNDU2Nzg5MDEyMzQ1Njc4OTA=" | openssl enc -d -a`(68 characters) and that does not work without `-A`. (Version 1.0.2n). Output of base64 encodings are 64 bytes as well.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek: **add a line terminator** (either Unix \n or Windows \r\n). The input for plain `-d -a` must be _lines_ not exceeding the limit, and even a shorter value like 32 chars with no terminator will fail. Similarly encoding without `-A` the output always has at least one terminator. (What can be more confusing is if you have an input file with several lines and the last isn't terminated, but the others of course are because that's necessary to have multiple lines, then you get a decode with _part_ of your data.)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: wow, this is confusing, thanks for correcting. More experiments show different behavior between different 1.0.2 versions as well (comparing 1.0.2d and 1.0.2n for example).

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek: I've never seen a difference other than the one at 1.1.0+ and would be interested in your evidence, but I'm afraid if we keep this up much longer we may anger the comment gods.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: The differences I mentioned might no longer be all that relevant, given that the [OpenSSL 1.0.2 Series Release Notes](https://www.openssl.org/news/openssl-1.0.2-notes.html) mention "Rewrite EVP_DecodeUpdate (base64 decoding) to fix several bugs" for release 1.0.2e. However, I think a complete description of the exact intricacies/differences of the different base64 mechanisms (EVP encode routines, `openssl enc` app, base64 `BIO`) would be pretty useful.

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek: adding both -a and -A fixed the problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to hear that. I will clarify the answer a bit about using both options at the same time.